# how to know apk size reduction after dynamic feature

Tags: android, app-bundle, dynamic-feature

I have separated one module of my project as dynamic feature module. But how I will test to know that how much (kb or mb) size has been reduced after I separated my module. It will be better if it will be possible without uploading apk into google play store(internal track)

Answer (score 0):

this can be done in simple steps:

step 1: build apk in your android Studio.

step 2: In the event log it will show options to locate or analyze the apk.

[image]

step 3: click on analyze Apk, there you can see the total size of the apk with the distribution of the size to resources, assests etc.

[image]

step4: you can also compare previos and current Apk so that you can get the detailed overview of the changes in the size of the Apk and the also on which resource the size reduced or increased

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: But this doesn't show module wise size distribution.

Comment: nope it will not show you the size distribution with code modules , but you can compare the difference in the apk sizes of new and older apk. However, the classes.dex size will show the difference for the changes in the java codes.